# Loading movie into created movieclip - target vanishes(?)

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I feel like I have done this a million times before just fine, but in this instance it is simply failing:

I am creating a movieclip and loading an external swf file into it, something like the following:

```
large_poem_clip_display = preview_clip._parent.attachMovie ("cyber poem display window" , "cyber_display" , preview_clip._parent.getNextHighestDepth() );
large_poem_clip_display.load_here.createEmptyMovieClip("inside",1);
large_poem_clip_display.load_here.inside.loadMovie( "path/to/swf" ) ;
```

All the movieclips involved seem to exist - they trace sensible values, but when I try the loadMovie I get the following error:

```
Target not found: Target="/cyber_display/load_here/inside" Base="_level0.cyber_display.load_here.inside"
```

I am currently just going around in circles, anyone got any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i fully understand your code, but your first line of code here seems to be the problem. You're declaring large_poem_clip_display as a variable; 
You can't use an attachMovie method as a variable value.

I would recommend doing your attachmovie first. 
Then on a separate line, set your large_poem_clip_display to the instance name of the new movie you've just attached.

Something like:

```
preview_clip.attachMovie ("cyber poem display window" , "cyber_display" , preview_clip.getNextHighestDepth() );
large_poem_clip_display = preview_clip.cyber_display;
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: attachMovie will return a reference to the movieclip that I just attached, if I did trace(large_poem_clip_display), it traced out the expected value, so I don't think that was the problem.
I do have it working now, although I am still a little confuzzled at exactly what the problem was.
Thanks.